# No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring + JPA + Hibernate in an application.I am facing below issue while jettty web server starts(during initialization)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [commonApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
```

My configuration file are below.

***commonApplicationContext.xml-->***

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.common.dao.*" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!--tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="defaultTransactionManager"/-->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="common"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.common.dao.entity"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

**persistence.xml -->**

```
<persistence-unit name="common" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.ejb.autodetection" value="class"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
             <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="20"/>
             <property name="hibernate.c3p0.initial_Pool_Size" value="20"/>
             <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100"/>
             <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="120"/>
             <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
             <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: It seems that <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> is not read in your persistence file. Try to set the persistenceProviderClassName property in your entityManagerFactory bean instead.

Comment: How to set that in entityManagerFactory bean??

Comment: <property name="persistenceProviderClassName" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" /> in your declaration of entityManagerFactory.

Comment: just tested getting below..Invalid property 'persistenceProviderClassName' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Bean property 'persistenceProviderClassName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: i think persistenceProviderClassName property is not available in entityManagerFactory bean.

Comment: Yes, sorry it's in another class: have you the hibernate-entitymanager dependency included ?

Comment: Yes it is there,<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: try to add  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"><bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" /></property> in entityManagerFactory bean definition to mapp to correct provider...

Comment: the same error exactly?

Comment: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66190/discussion-between-re350-and-rlm).